# Position-dodge warning with ggplot boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to make a boxplot with ggplot2 using the following code:

```
p <- ggplot(
      data,
      aes(d$score, reorder(d$names d$scores, median))
     ) +
       geom_boxplot()
```

I have factors called names and integers called scores.

My code produces a plot, but the graphic does not depict the boxes (only shows lines) and I get a warning message, "position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals." I've tried to adjust the height and width with `geom_boxplot(width=5)`, but this does not seem to fix the problem. Can anyone suggest a possible solution to my problem?

I should point out that my boxplot is rather large and has about 200 name values on the y-axis). Perhaps this is the problem?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The number of groups is not the problem; I can see the same thing even when there are only 2 groups.  The issue is that `ggplot2` draws boxplots vertically (continuous along y, categorical along x) and you are trying to draw them horizontally (continuous along x, categorical along y).

Also, your example has several syntax errors and isn't reproducible because we don't have `data`/`d`.

Start with some mock data

```
dat <- data.frame(scores=rnorm(1000,sd=500), 
                  names=sample(LETTERS, 1000, replace=TRUE))
```

Corrected version of your example code:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(scores, reorder(names, scores, median))) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image: ggplot(dat, aes(scores, reorder(names, scores, median))) + geom_boxplot()]

This is the horizontal lines you saw.

If you instead put the categorical on the x axis and the continuous on the y you get

```
ggplot(dat, aes(reorder(names, scores, median), scores)) + geom_boxplot()
```

[image: ggplot(dat, aes(reorder(names, scores, median), scores)) + geom_boxplot()]

Finally, if you want to flip the coordinate axes, you can use `coord_flip()`.  There can be some additional problems with this if you are doing even more sophisticated things, but for basic boxplots it works.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(reorder(names, scores, median), scores)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()
```

[image: ggplot(dat, aes(reorder(names, scores, median), scores)) + geom_boxplot() + coord_flip()]

Comment: Wow, thank you! This is precisely the problem I was having. I greatly appreciate the thorough answer.

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else arrives here wondering ***why*** they're seeing

> Warning message:
>
> position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals

#### Why this happens

The reason this happens is because some of the boxplot / violin plot (or other plot type) are possibly overlapping. In many cases, you may not care, but in some cases, it matters, hence why it warns you.

#### How to fix it

You have two options. Either [suppress warnings when generating/printing the ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13286617/5783745)

The other option, simply alter the width of the plot so that the plots don't overlap, then the warning goes away. Try altering the `width` argument to the geom: e.g. `geom_boxplot(width = 0.5)` (same works for `geom_violin()`)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @stevec's options, if you're seeing

- `position_stack requires non-overlapping x intervals`
- `position_fill requires non-overlapping x intervals`
- `position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals`
- `position_dodge2 requires non-overlapping x intervals`

and if your x variable is supposed to overlap for different aesthetics such as fill, you can try making the x_var into a factor:

`geom_bar(aes(x = factor(x_var), fill = type)`