# How to suppress warnings when plotting with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

When passing missing values to ggplot, it's very kind, and warns us that they are present. This is acceptable in an interactive session, but when writing reports, you do not the output get cluttered with warnings, especially if there's many of them. Below example has one label missing, which produces a warning.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
mydf <- data.frame(
  species = sample(c("A", "B"), 100, replace = TRUE), 
  lvl = factor(sample(1:3, 100, replace = TRUE))
)
labs <- melt(with(mydf, table(species, lvl)))
names(labs) <- c("species", "lvl", "value")
labs[3, "value"] <- NA
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = species)) + 
   stat_bin() + 
   geom_text(data = labs, aes(x = species, y = value, label = value, vjust = -0.5)) +
   facet_wrap(~ lvl)
```

[image]

If we wrap `suppressWarnings` around the last expression, we get a summary of how many warnings there were. For the sake of argument, let's say that this isn't acceptable (but is indeed very honest and correct). How to (completely) suppress warnings when printing a ggplot2 object?

Comment: Since you mention reporting: you can suppress warnings output in knitr.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

A more targeted plot-by-plot approach would be to add `na.rm=TRUE` to your plot calls. 
E.g.:

```
  ggplot(mydf, aes(x = species)) + 
      stat_bin() + 
      geom_text(data = labs, aes(x = species, y = value, 
                                 label = value, vjust = -0.5), na.rm=TRUE) +
      facet_wrap(~ lvl)
```

Comment: +1 Nice answer. It's always going to better to address the root cause of warnings and deal with these, rather than suppressing the warnings.

Comment: +1 Agree with @Andrie, although I do find it reassuring to get the warning about missing values - it helps me have a check that it is doing the right thing. Not that I don't trust Hadley of course.

Comment: FYI: For `stat_smooth` this technique doesn't work. (bug)

Answer (score 76):

You need to `suppressWarnings()` around the `print()` call, not the creation of the `ggplot()` object:

```
R> suppressWarnings(print(
+ ggplot(mydf, aes(x = species)) + 
+    stat_bin() + 
+    geom_text(data = labs, aes(x = species, y = value, 
+                               label = value, vjust = -0.5)) +
+    facet_wrap(~ lvl)))
R>
```

It might be easier to assign the final plot to an object and then `print()`.

```
plt <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = species)) + 
   stat_bin() + 
   geom_text(data = labs, aes(x = species, y = value,
                              label = value, vjust = -0.5)) +
   facet_wrap(~ lvl)


R> suppressWarnings(print(plt))
R>
```

The reason for the behaviour is that the warnings are only generated when the plot is actually drawn, not when the object representing the plot is created. R will auto print during interactive usage, so whilst

```
R> suppressWarnings(plt)
Warning message:
Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_text).
```

doesn't work because, in effect, you are calling `print(suppressWarnings(plt))`, whereas

```
R> suppressWarnings(print(plt))
R>
```

does work because `suppressWarnings()` can capture the warnings arising from the `print()` call.

Comment: Interesting how explicitly calling `print` works but not when this is done implicitly by calling `ggplot` and not assigning it to an object.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik That's because the actual call is something like `print(suppressWarnings(plt))` where you want `suppressWarnings(print(plt))` or did I miss what you meant?

Comment: Yes, you've nailed it. I didn't think hard enough about how print is being called implicitly.

Comment: How to remove any message from `ggplot` ?

Comment: I got message such as 
``geom_line()`: Each group consists of only one observation.
ℹ Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?`

Comment: @Julien See `?tryCatch` for more detail, but also, this might relate to how the Posit folks are now doing better error messages and formatting them so actually handling this generically  could be more involved. Note this Q&A is over a decade old and **ggplot2** has changed considerably in the meantime. You might do well to formulate your own question (linking to this Q&A to indicate why the approach here doesn't work now) and ask on [so]

Answer (score 31):

In your question, you mention report writing, so it might be better to set the global warning level:

```
options(warn=-1)
```

the default is:

```
options(warn=0)
```

Comment: It does not seem to work in a R script