# Supressing Warnings in scale_x_datetime

Tags: r, ggplot2, timezone, axis-labels, suppress-warnings

This is not a duplicate since none of the methods in that putative duplicate apply here. None of them lead to the warning going away.

In fact I got an answer here from Konrad below - use `suppressMessages`. In the link that is asserted as a possible duplicate, they suggest `suppressWarnings`, which does not work.

---

After finally figuring out how to get R to use my timezone on the `ggplot` date axis correctly (found `scale_x_datetime` in a post here, before it was using my local timezone even though the data had the timezone set already), but it now complains with a warning:

```
Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.
```

This is annoying because I have to do this a lot, and don't want to get in the habit of ignore all warnings. How can I turn this off? I obviously have tried `suppressWarnings` (with and without print) and `options(warn=-1).`

- R-Version is 3.1.3
- ggplot2_1.0.1
- scales_0.2.4

  ```
  library(lubridate,quietly=T,warn.conflicts=T)
  library(ggplot2,quietly=T,warn.conflicts=T)
  library(scales,quietly=T,warn.conflicts=T)


  sclip.time <-  ymd_hms("2014-06-16 00:00:00",tz="US/Pacific")
  eclip.time <-  ymd_hms("2014-06-17 23:59:59",tz="US/Pacific")

  sdata.time <-  ymd_hms("2014-06-16 00:00:00",tz="US/Pacific")
  edata.time <-  ymd_hms("2014-06-17 23:59:59",tz="US/Pacific")


  xdata <- seq(sdata.time,edata.time,length.out=100)  
  xfrac <- seq(0,4*3.1416,length.out=100)
  ydata <- pmax(0.25,sin(xfrac))
  ydata <- sin(xfrac)
  ddf <- data.frame(x=xdata,y=ydata)

  date_format_tz <- function(format = "%Y-%m-%d", tz = "UTC") {
    function(x) format(x, format, tz=tz)
  }

  options(warn=-1)

  suppressWarnings(
  ggplot(ddf) + 
    geom_line(aes(x,y),col="blue") +
    geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(sclip.time),color="darkred") +
    geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(eclip.time),color="darkgreen") +
    xlim(sclip.time,edata.time) +
    scale_x_datetime(  breaks = date_breaks("1 day"),
                       labels = date_format_tz("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="US/Pacific"))
  )
  ```

  [image]

Comment: I think it is the default behaviour and this message cannot be suppressed.

Comment: To not be able to suppress a warning?

Comment: No, this specific message.

Comment: So this message always comes? So isn't really a warning?

Comment: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_datetime.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to suppress warnings when plotting with ggplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286531/how-to-suppress-warnings-when-plotting-with-ggplot)

Comment: Not a duplicate since they managed to get rid of the warnings. In this case I don't see a way to use the function without getting the warning.

Comment: As Pacal points out you even see the warning in the documentation...

Comment: You have to use supressMessages, not supressWarnings

Comment: For this particular case, the easiest thing to do is to put the x limits inside the scale function: scale_x_datetime(breaks = whatever, labels = whatever, limits = c(sclip.time,edata.time))

Comment: This is worth writing up as an answer (with code). I would upvote it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the combination of `suppressMessages` and `print` as in the snippet below:

```
suppressMessages(print(
  ggplot(ddf) + 
    geom_line(aes(x,y),col="blue") +
    geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(sclip.time),color="darkred") +
    geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(eclip.time),color="darkgreen") +
    xlim(sclip.time,edata.time) +
    scale_x_datetime(  breaks = date_breaks("1 day"),
                       labels = date_format_tz("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="US/Pacific"))
))
```

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Tried it again just not to be sure. Still didn't work.

Comment: @MikeWise, very odd I tried the code and it [runs fine](http://pastebin.com/QhszRDWL).

Comment: I still have the warning. Would love to know how you got rid of it.

Comment: That was it. I just noticed you used supressMessages, I was trying supressWarnings. By the way you don't have to use a print (in this case), it goes away without it.

Comment: suppressMessages() without print() worked for me too. Just in case you are getting the plot object the command will be: suppressMessages(p <- ggplot(...))

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the message does point to a problem with your following code snippet:

```r
  ... + xlim(sclip.time,edata.time) +
  scale_x_datetime(  breaks = date_breaks("1 day"),
                     labels = date_format_tz("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="US/Pacific"))
```

Already the first command will add a scale, and the second command will replace that scale.  So the message tells you that the first command has no effect.

You should combine the two and add the limits to `scale_x_datetime`:

```r
  ... +
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = date_breaks("1 day"),
                   labels = date_format_tz("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", tz="US/Pacific"),
                   limits = c(sclip.time,edata.time))
```

Answer (score 1):

A way you might get what you want is to use the "try" function, with the option silent=T :

```
try(silent=T, [R-script])
```

It is generally a bad idea to do it that way, because you become blind to the errors that might occur, but if you are really certain of what you're doing..