# How can I remove a scale from a ggplot object?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function that returns a ggplot object that already has a line type scale.  Now I want to change the scale.  If I simply add a new scale, I get a message: `"Scale for '...' is already present."`

The question how to suppress that message has already been asked on stackoverflow (e.g. [Supressing Warnings in scale_x_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823327/supressing-warnings-in-scale-x-datetime/29823510)).  The only simple solution seems to be to suppress *all* messages - which I don't want, in order not to overlook something.  So the natural alternative would be: Remove the present scale first, and then add another scale.

Can that be done easily?

Example (under the assumption that I'm not allowed to change the definition of `f`):

```r
> f <- function() ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + geom_point() + xlim(c(11, 34))
> g <- f()
> g + xlim(c(9, 36))
Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale.
```

Answer (score 4):

One possibility that seems to work with ggplot2-3.3.0:

```r
> g <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + geom_point() + xlim(c(11, 34))
> g$scales$scales <- list()
> g + xlim(c(9, 36))
```

Comment: I want to remove one scale but not all. Is there a way to inspect the `g$scales$scales` list to figure out which attribute is scaled by each entry?

Answer (score 0):

I have the feeling that you are overlooking the most simple solution:

```
g.aux <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) + geom_point()
```

Then you could do either:

```
g1 <- g.aux + xlim(c(11, 34))
g2 <- g.aux + xlim(c(9, 36))
```

Or

```
g <- g.aux + xlim(c(11, 34))
#Do what you need with "g". Then redefine it as
g <- g.aux + xlim(c(9, 36))
##Do what you need with the new "g"
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The problem is that in my setting I don't have direct access to `g.aux`.  Instead, I only have a function that gives `g1` to me.  Sorry for not making that clear enough in the question.

Comment: I see... Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940000/modifying-ggplot-objects-after-creation

Comment: Thanks for the link. So the question is:  If I "build" the plot, is it easier to manipulate afterwards?  I will look into that.