# Why is a geom_path warning message being displayed when I try to display faceted line graphs using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create multiple line graphs using ggplot, geom_line and facet_wrap. The chart is created and displayed successfully, however the following message is also displayed along with the chart:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

[image]

I've already tried restarting my session, restarting R, searching for answers by Googling, searching here on Stack Overflow (including the following question: [ggplot2 line chart gives "geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082601/ggplot2-line-chart-gives-geom-path-each-group-consist-of-only-one-observation)) and can't find anything that helps.

Adding:

```
group=1
```

...doesn't eliminate the warning message.

The version of RStudio I'm using is: Version 1.1.463.

The code is in an RMarkdown file that I'm knitting to create an HTML document.

The libraries I'm using in this Rmarkdown file are:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(operators)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(sf)
library(usmap)
library(waffle)
```

The structure of the data set that I'm using in the chart is:

```
'data.frame':   75 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Year         : int  1998 1993 1998 1999 2005 2007 2014 2018 1989 1991 ...
 $ Age_Bracket  : chr  "1-12" "13-19" "13-19" "13-19" ...
 $ Num_Shootings: num  1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 ...
```

The code that generates the warning message is:

```
# Create a faceted line graph showing the number of mass shootings per year for each age bracket

faceted_line_graph_year_age <- ggplot(data=shootings_per_year_age, aes(x=Year, y = Num_Shootings, colour = Age_Bracket, group=1)) + 
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", colour = "#666666", linetype = 2, size = 0.5 )+
  facet_wrap(~Age_Bracket)


# Display the faceted line graph

faceted_line_graph_year_age
```

The message I see is:

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to
## adjust the group aesthetic?
```

I'm expecting the chart to be displayed without a warning message.
What I'm getting is the chart displayed with a warning message.

Comment: I *think* the error is caused by `geom_line` in the first group, because it cannot draw a line with only a single point there. This is also a warning/message (not sure which exactly here) but not an error, which would not have let you produce the graph at all. Warnings/messages are mostly to let you know you might be doing something wrong, not fatal

Comment: Thanks Calam. I removed the first age category and now it displays the charts without the message. Thank you! I've edited my description to replace error with warning message. I don't suppose you know if there's a way I could tell R to not display the message if I wanted to leave the first age category in?

Comment: @Teaching_myself_how_to_code The message (which is technically neither an error nor a warning, but a diagnostic message) is hard-coded into the underlying plotting function over at `GeomPath$draw_panel`, & I don't see anything there that could suppress the message.

Comment: Run your code inside `suppressWarnings(...)` if you don't want to see warnings in a particular chunk of code. Or set `options(warn=...)` to -1 - see `help(options)` to see what the other values do.

Comment: @CalumYou It is definitely caused by `geom_line`. If this geom can be removed without compromising the intent of the plot that is the simplest way to go.

Comment: @Spacedman I have not had success with those options as the print out isn't a warning, it's created from this function: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/48580251e5cb006863edf102376815c379ae1fcf/R/utilities.r#L305-L309 which is called here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/10fa0014d6be81a7e641b8c2c3b48e1df1b7e2f5/R/geom-path.r#L153-L156 which itself calls `message` from base. Therefore `suppressMessage()` _should_ correct for this, but doesn't for reasons I don't understand. I can only guess that somewhere between `geom_path` + `message_wrap` it changes type.

Comment: @Teaching_myself_how_to_code I think there is a 'solution' here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48197537/2902740

Note this may not be suitable as it requires an explicit print call to an assigned plot object, so YMMV.

Comment: If you are in knitr, you can use `message=FALSE` for the chunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to user [calum-you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7028459/calum-you) for the answer:

> I think the error is caused by geom_line in the first group, because it cannot draw a line with only a single point there. This is also a warning/message (not sure which exactly here) but not an error, which would not have let you produce the graph at all. Warnings/messages are mostly to let you know you might be doing something wrong, not fatal

I removed the plot representing the fist age category (as there was only one data value for that plot) and the issue was resolved.