# Overlay geom_point to geom_bar. How to align the points and bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, overlay, point

I have been trying this for enough time and I just have to ask... It seems very basic and it has probably been asked before, but I cannot find any post that applies to my particular situation.

Really simple, I have 2 data frames with the same grouping variables but different data I want to plot together, one as bars, and another as points on top.

I am using `mtcars` for this example. I have my ID variables as the car model, then I use two grouping variables `carb` and `cyl` that are in both my data frames.

One data frame has the `max disp` value per `carb` and `cyl` so it's shorter (I filled in missing values as 0 for all the `carb`-`cyl` combinations); I want to plot it as bars.

The other data frame has the individual `disp` values per model, and I want to plot it on top as points.

This is my approach, but the resulting plot is really wrong, the colors and points positions need to be adjusted there... Ideally I would like all points to be black, but I seem to only have them separated by group if I do `color`. For the positioning, it goes inside a function so should work for any number of levels in the data frame grouping variables.

```
mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(as.character(mtcars$cyl))
mtcars$carb <- as.factor(as.character(mtcars$carb))

mydf1 <- as.data.frame(data.table::data.table(mtcars)[, list(max=max(disp)), by=list(cyl=cyl, carb=carb)])

mydf2 <- mtcars[,c(2,3,11,12)]
zerodf <- expand.grid(cyl=unique(mtcars$cyl), carb=unique(mtcars$carb))

mydf1 <- merge(mydf1, zerodf, all=TRUE)
mydf1$max[which(is.na(mydf1$max))] <- 0

P <- ggplot2::ggplot(data=NULL) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(data=mydf1, ggplot2::aes(carb, max, fill=cyl), position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  ggplot2::scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","red","grey"))

P <- P + ggplot2::geom_point(data=mydf2, ggplot2::aes(carb, disp, color=cyl), position=ggplot2::position_dodge(width=0.5), shape=3, size=5, show.legend=FALSE)
```

[image: test]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple issue is the coloring of the points. To get black points simply map `cyl` on the `group` aesthetic in the `geom_point` layer. The tricky part is the positioning. To get the positioning of the points right you have to fill up `mydf2` to include all combinations of `cyl` and `carb` as you have already done for `mydf1`. To this end I use `tidyr::complete`. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mtcars$model <- rownames(mtcars)
#head(mtcars)

mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(as.character(mtcars$cyl))
mtcars$carb <- as.factor(as.character(mtcars$carb))
#summary(mtcars)
mydf1 <- as.data.frame(data.table::data.table(mtcars)[, list(max=max(disp)), by=list(cyl=cyl, carb=carb)])

mydf2 <- mtcars[,c(2,3,11,12)]

zerodf <- expand.grid(cyl=unique(mtcars$cyl), carb=unique(mtcars$carb))
mydf1 <- merge(mydf1, zerodf, all=TRUE)
mydf1$max[which(is.na(mydf1$max))] <- 0

mydf2 <- tidyr::complete(mydf2, carb, cyl)

ggplot(data = NULL, aes(group = cyl)) +
  geom_bar(data=mydf1, aes(carb, max, fill=cyl), position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue","red","grey")) +
  geom_point(data=mydf2, aes(carb, disp, group=cyl), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), shape=3, size=5, show.legend=FALSE)
#> Warning: Removed 9 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Comment: just a bit bothered with the `warnings` here... any way of taking care of them?

Comment: and another question... in case I wanted to keep the group coloring for the points... why if I do `color=cyl` in `geom_point` I don't get the same `blue`, `red`, `grey` colors?

Comment: Each aesthetic has its own scale. With `scale_fill_manual` you set colors for the `fill` aes. To set the palette for the `color` aes you have to add `scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","red","grey"))` or add the additional argument `aesthetics = c("fill", "color")` to `scale_fill_manual`.

Comment: oh right! sorry that was a silly question... can we hide the warnings or avoid them?

Comment: (: Good question. And the answer is yes. Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286531/how-to-suppress-warnings-when-plotting-with-ggplot one can add `na.rm = TRUE` to `geom_point` to suppress the warnings.