# position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am still a new user to R and ggplot and was looking for some help. For starters,I have a similar set of data as the mtcar and followed the below to help create plots:
http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/ggplot2.html
Specifically, I hope to create similar graph as below with Y and X-axis flipped: http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/images/ggplotboxplot.png

However, the graph I obtained is as follows with the error message 
"Warning message:
position_dodge requires non-overlapping x intervals" and obtained the graph below:
[image: Graph]

my code is as below:

```
qplot(AGE_In_Years, Trial , data=Study_intensive_1, geom=c("boxplot", "jitter"), 
      fill=Trial, main="Title",
      xlab="x-axis", ylab="Y axis")
```

I found this on forum, but this there a method to introduce jitter?
[Position-dodge warning with ggplot boxplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522527/position-dodge-warning-with-ggplot-boxplot)

Is there a way to fix this? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Try `ggboxploth` from the `ggstance` package, and then change your code to `geom=c("boxploth", "jitter")`. `ggstance` has horizontal versions of the standard geoms.