# diagnosing why custom function produces unexpected warning (about position_jitterdodge)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, plyr, rlang

I am copy-pasting a simplified version of a custom function I am working with. The function works fine, but it's the `warnings` it produces that I haven't been able to get rid off. This function is going to be part of a package and thus it's important for the users to not be thrown off by these cryptic errors and I would, therefore, like to change the script in a way that these warnings will no longer be produced.

The warning is (see the fully reproducible example below):

```
position_jitterdodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

I have already checked this question about `position_jitterdodge` ([Position-dodge warning with ggplot boxplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522527/position-dodge-warning-with-ggplot-boxplot)) and it wasn't much of a help since there is no boxplot in this figure.

Apologies for the protracted nature of the question and the code. Wanted to provide all possible details to help diagnose this.

```r
# loading needed libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("daattali/ggExtra")
library(ggExtra) # attach the development version
library(rlang)

# defining the custom function
ggscatterstats <-
  function(data = NULL,
           x,
           y,
           xfill = "orange",
           yfill = "green",
           marginal = NULL,
           marginaltype = "histogram",
           jitter.width = NULL,
           jitter.height = 0.2,
           dodge.width = 0.75) {
    # preparing a dataframe out of provided inputs
    if (!is.null(data)) {
      # if dataframe is provided
      data <-
        dplyr::select(
          .data = data,
          x = !!rlang::enquo(x),
          y = !!rlang::enquo(y)
        )
    } else {
      # if vectors are provided
      data <-
        base::cbind.data.frame(x = x,
                               y = y)
    }

    # preparing the scatterplotplot
    plot <-
      ggplot2::ggplot(data = data,
                      mapping = aes(x = x,
                                    y = y)) +
      geom_count(
        show.legend = FALSE,
        colour = "black",
        size = 3,
        alpha = 0.5,
        position = position_jitterdodge(
          jitter.width = jitter.width,
          jitter.height = jitter.height,
          dodge.width = dodge.width
        )
      ) +
      geom_smooth(method = "lm",
                  se = TRUE,
                  size = 1.5) +
      theme_grey()

    # marginal plot will be shown by default
    if (is.null(marginal))
      marginal <- TRUE

    if (isTRUE(marginal)) {          
      # creating the ggMarginal plot of a given marginaltype
      plot <-
        ggExtra::ggMarginal(
          p = plot,
          type = marginaltype,
          size = 5,
          xparams = list(fill = xfill,
                               col = "black"),
          yparams = list(fill = yfill,
                               col = "black")
        )
    }

    return(plot)

  }

# using the function
ggscatterstats(data = iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width)
#> Warning: position_jitterdodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
#> Warning: position_jitterdodge requires non-overlapping x intervals
```

[image]

Created on 2018-02-15 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A minimal example is easier to discuss.

This is a minimal example adapted from your code that produce this warning :

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_count(size = 3, alpha = 0.5, position = position_jitterdodge())
```

I don't understand what you are trying to do here. I might be wrong but there seems to be a use of tools/concepts that should not be used together.

The whole point of `geom_count` is to deal with overplottig by representing the number of observations on a given x y pair of coordinates with the size of the point. So you should not set the size and jittering/dodging is unnecessary too :

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_count()
```

[image]

Another possibility is to use `geom_point` that you can combine with jittering but combining jittering with dodging does not seem to make sense here either:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) + 
    geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5, position = position_jitter())
```

[image]

Jittering + dodging seem to make sense only when you have a discrete x axis and an additional aestetic to dodge by. Here we create an artificial additional "sex" variable to be maped to the color aestetic for the demonstration.

```
iris$Sex <- factor(c("M", "F"))
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width, color = Sex)) + 
    geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5, position = position_jitterdodge())
```

[image]

If all this does not make sense, could you please explain why you need `geom_count` with a fixed size (more precisely a "set size" in the ggplot lingo) and a combination of jittering and dodging ?

Comment: the warning happens in `ggplot2:::collide` where intervals are defined (on your last graph here these intervals are the space between the red dots and the corresponding green dots). We can reproduce OP's warnings by running `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Width, color = Sex)) + geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.5, position = position_jitterdodge(dodge.width = 3))`

Comment: OP could remove these warnings by running `ggscatterstats(data = iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Width,dodge.width = 0.1)` but as your answer details, better first to make sure that the current approach make sense.